# mysql error, springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: I got the error msg, couldn't find why

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1064, badsqlgrammarexception

I got the error.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (productId, address, productName, price, imageUrl) VALUES ('000', 'address' at line 1
### The error may involve Order.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO order (productId, address, productName, price, imageUrl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (productId, address, productName, price, imageUrl) VALUES ('000', 'address' at line 1
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (productId, address, productName, price, imageUrl) VALUES ('000', 'address' at line 1
    at
```

I looked at my xml as the error log told me.

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.whiuni.fastshop.vo.OrderVO">
        INSERT INTO order (productId, address, productName, price, imageUrl) VALUES (#{productId}, #{address}, #{productName}, #{price}, #{imageUrl})
</insert>
```

Could anyone tell me what the error is? Thank you

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Finding minimal code with your error involves finding code with no error. PS The FK productId is string. What is the type of the PK it references? PS 6 columns. PS It seems unlikely that this is not a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: @philipxy Thank you. I changed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in mysql, change the table name or surround it with single-quotes

```
INSERT INTO 'order' (productId, address, productName, price, imageUrl) ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I surround order with `, and it works.